# Speeding up this code (opening workbooks)

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to speed up this code as it's currently taking ~22 seconds to run and i'm sure it can be done much smarter than i'm able to with my current level of ability.

I'm confident the delay is being caused by opening the other workbooks, so just trying to figure out how to smarten this process up.

Basically I have 60 versions of this spreadsheet (1 for each department) using this code to update the data when the datasheet is generated through BisTalk each morning, this to supply departments with an up to date forecast of their wage spend.

It opens these sheets in order to refresh the data in the document (essentially only needs to open and then close these 3 workbooks), so changes made can be done from 1 workbook and flow through all 60 of these workbooks when departments open the doc and run the update button performing the below macro.

Edit: Using methods below and using timers all the time is coming from opening wb3 (6.8s) & wb5 (5.8s). So if I can somehow speed those up it would have a massive effect, the remainder of the macro takes 3.25s to process.

```
Public CalcState As Long
Public EventState As Boolean
Public PageBreakState As Boolean

Sub OptimizeCode_Begin()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

EventState = Application.EnableEvents
Application.EnableEvents = False

CalcState = Application.Calculation
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

PageBreakState = ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

End Sub

Sub OptimizeCode_End()

ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = PageBreakState
Application.Calculation = CalcState
Application.EnableEvents = EventState
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


Sub UpdateForecaster()

' UpdateForecaster
' *************************************

' Blocking the ability to pause macro due to sensitive information
    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled

'Optimize Code
  Call OptimizeCode_Begin


Dim Main As Workbook
Set Main = ActiveWorkbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim wb3 As Workbook
Dim wb4 As Workbook
Dim wb5 As Workbook

'Opening Data Sheets
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("Sheet with the workbook paths, so can easily be updated within rather than updating the code on the 60 versions of this document for each store", ReadOnly:=True)
Dim directory1 As String
Dim directory2 As String
    directory1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
    directory2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Value

    Set wb3 = Workbooks.Open(directory1, ReadOnly:=True, Password:="password")
    Set wb4 = Workbooks.Open(directory2, ReadOnly:=True)
    Set wb5 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:= _
    "datasheet", ReadOnly:=True, Password:="password")
    wb5.Close
    Main.Activate

'Refreshing Cell Information
    Range("D4").Formula = "=d97"
    Range("D5").Formula = "=d98"
    Range("D6").Formula = "=d99"
    Range("D7").Formula = "=d100"
    Range("D10").Formula = "=d103"
    Range("D11").Formula = "=d104"
    Range("D12").Formula = "=d105"
    Range("D13").Formula = "=d106"

    ('Same as above across other columns to refresh')              

    ' Close Workbooks
    wb3.Close False
    wb4.Close False
    wb2.Close False

'Optimize Code
  Call OptimizeCode_End

End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("D4:D7").Formula = "=D97"`. `Range("D10:D13").Formula = "=D103"`. You can write a formula to an entire range, and Excel will update the relative references. So you can probably simplify whatever you're doing with other columns.

Comment: In fact, if you need multiple columns to do the same, eg: `Range("D4:D7,F4:F7,H4:H7.....etc....").Formula = "=D97"` Either way, iterating over `Range` objects is slow. So you might want to ask the question "Do I need the formulas?". If the answer is no, then you might want to work through memory which is faster.

Comment: Cool, that's good to know, updated the above to simplify as only 3 lines of ranges instead of the plethora it was. I believe it reduced the run time a little, seems to be ~19s to run, so helped. Thanks

Comment: It would help your efforts to speed up your code if you use `Timer` and put some `Debug.Print` statements in your code to find out where the most time is being taken

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams, that was super helpful. Found an error with my ```Call OptimizeCode_End``` part of it that I likely would not have found otherwise. So that shaved 9s off where it was erroring in the background. The brunt is the opening of the workbooks, 1 in particular since it's a large file with the budgeting information for every account which takes ~6s to open.

Comment: I have found when you declare variables and the order in which you use them can impact the time a macro takes to run.

Comment: I see, the order I use is
```Sub OptimizeCode_Begin()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

End Sub```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like 1 quickfire way to speed this up by a decent margin was to change the other workbook files to binary .xlsb which reduced the load time of these files to a third of what they were.